# Configuración IE 11 para que permita JavaScript por default

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-11

Solicito de su apoyo ya que estamos haciendo pruebas con html dentro de este tenemos un scripts el cuando ejecuta un "Hola mundo" pero al momento de abrirlo con Internet de explorer arroja la siguiente leyenda "Internet Explorer no permitió que esta pagina web ejecutara Scripts o controles ActiveX en el equipo" , ya se realizaron las configuraciones de seguridad para activar los Scripts y ActiveX en IE. mas sin embargo el problema persiste.

Espero puedan apoyarme , gracias.[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Quizá dando clic en el botón Permitir contenido bloqueado.

Comment: Lo que tratamos de hacer es que el permitir contenido bloqueado , se realice automáticamente y no manual. ya que usamos lo estamos ejecutando desde una aplicación.

Comment: Me meto que no puedes. Si eso existiera crearía un agujero de seguridad enorme.